# iOS Custom View - init with CGRect.zero - Constraint warning

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, warnings

I've got a custom view with two labels underneath each other. The view init method looks like this

```
self.locationView = LocationView(frame: CGRect.zero)
```

For positioning the subview inside the main view, I use the following constraints:

```
        self.gMapsView.addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
            withVisualFormat: "H:|-[locationView]-|",
            options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: UInt(0)),
            metrics: nil,
            views: views
        )
    )

    self.gMapsView.addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
            withVisualFormat: "V:[locationView]-(paddingBottom)-|",
            options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: UInt(0)),
            metrics: [
                "paddingBottom": LOCATION_VIEW_CONFIG.paddingBottom
            ],
            views: views
        )
    )
```

For positioning the labels inside the location view I use the following constraints:

```
        self.addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
            withVisualFormat: "H:|[streetLabel]|",
            options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: UInt(0)),
            metrics: nil,
            views: views
        )
    )

    self.addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
            withVisualFormat: "H:|[cityLabel]|",
            options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: UInt(0)),
            metrics: nil,
            views: views
        )
    )

    self.addConstraints(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
            withVisualFormat: "V:|-[streetLabel]-[cityLabel]-|",
            options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: UInt(0)),
            metrics: nil,
            views: views
        )
    )
```

Unfortunately I'm getting constraint warnings:

```
(
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x608000280820 h=--& v=--& Test.LocationView:0x7fdc40f0c780.height == 0   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000280190 UILabel:0x7fdc40f0cb40.top == Test.LocationView:0x7fdc40f0c780.topMargin   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000280320 V:[UILabel:0x7fdc40f0cb40]-(NSSpace(8))-[UILabel:0x7fdc40d155e0]   (active)>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6080002802d0 Test.LocationView:0x7fdc40f0c780.bottomMargin == UILabel:0x7fdc40d155e0.bottom   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x608000280320 V:[UILabel:0x7fdc40f0cb40]-(NSSpace(8))-[UILabel:0x7fdc40d155e0]   (active)>
```

How can i fix them? Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn off Autoresizing Mask, that's the first constraint (NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint) listed there that's conflicting with the ones you've created later. You can see that it's setting the height to 0. Add:

self.locationView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

There may be other issues yet with your layout, but that ought to solve the conflict.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I already had that code, but I called it after adding the view to the parent view.